# How to implement the incremental upgrade of application in android

Tags: java, android

How to implement  the incremental upgrade of application in android ?
In order to save traffic when the download

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you need to do to enable this.  Google Play Store automatically performs a diff on their side between the users current version and your new version and only downloads the differences (delta).

I'd presume if you re-factor your code significantly then this would trigger a full download but that's all behind the scenes and no way of specifying what happens yourself.

Comment: If it's not Google Play store and you've implemented your own/using a third party market store then that is really dependent on how the market implements downloads and is more server side than app side.  The server needs to do the diff otherwise it will download the whole app again to the device and diff there which defeats the purpose.

Comment: yes ,your analysis is correct.I found the information from http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/software-updates-courgette.But my English is not good .I didn't find the example code for this project